# Run right-click option through cmd

Tags: cmd, right-click

I need to run a right-click option through the command line. I have got the code, which I got from the registry, and now I want to run it through the command line. The program right-click option looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Company\Prog_vX.XX\bin\prog.exe" -param1 "%1"
```

My batch looks like this:

```
runas /user:Server
start "" "C:\Program Files\Company\Prog_vX.XX\bin\prog.exe" C:\files\file1.ext" -param1 "%1"
```

But this only opens the software. In this case, the right-click option only appears for this file extension (*.ext) and it is the second option.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Because your executable path and name is a big fat secret, I cannot say for sure but normal rules dictate that `%1` is replaced by the file name, i.e. `C:\files\file1.ext`. Your command would therefore look like this: `Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Company\Prog_vX.XX\bin\prog.exe" -param1 "C:\files\file1.ext"`

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!! It does not work.. It opens the software, just this.. I could not find any software to check the code behind the right-click option..

Comment: Sorry, it worked!!! Works like a charm!!!! Many thanks for your help!!!!!!